# Select two sums with different conditions MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a db table "entries" with time logs from employees.

```
employee_id    |    hours    |    task_id    |    logged_at
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1              |    .5       |    1          |    1546342200 (jan 19)
2              |    .8       |    2          |    1547548200 (jan 19)
1              |    .2       |    3          |    1549022400 (feb 19)
1              |    .5       |    3          |    1549022400 (feb 19)
2              |    .9       |    1          |    1551625200 (mar 19)
```

My goal is to pull a report that breaks out billable vs. non-billable hours for each month of the year. Billable vs. non-billable is determined by task ID. I have a list of task IDs that are billable and a list that are not.

Goal for end result

```
month    |    year    |    total   |    billable    |    nonbillable
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |    2019    |    1.3     |    .8          |    .5
2        |    2019    |    .7      |    .7          |    0
3        |    2019    |    .9      |    0           |    .9
```

This is based on tasks 2 and 3 being billable and task 1 as non-billable.

Please note this is a simplification of the real DB, which has about 25 different task IDs that occasionally change.

I was able to get the general idea going, but got stuck at separating billable hours vs non-billable hours based on task_id.

This is as far as I got:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)), 
  SUM(hours)
FROM dpd_harvest_entries
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have `tasks` table with column `billable` which holds 1 for billable tasks and 0 for non-billable tasks. then your query could look like:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)),
  SUM(hours) total,
  SUM(IF(t.billable,hours,0)) billable,
  SUM(IF(t.billable,0,hours)) nonbillable
FROM dpd_harvest_entries e
INNER JOIN tasks t
ON e.task_id = t.task_id
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at))
```

If you just hav comma separated `ids` you can transform this query to:

```
SELECT 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)),
  SUM(hours) total,
  SUM(IF(task_id IN ({your id list}),hours,0)) billable,
  SUM(IF(task_id IN ({your id list}),0,hours)) nonbillable
FROM dpd_harvest_entries e
GROUP BY 
  MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at)), 
  YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at))
```

Where `{your id list}` should be replaced with ex: `IN (1, 4, 55, 47)`

And for future use I would strongly recommend to `ALTER TABLE dpd_harvest_entries MODIFY logged_at DATETIME` that will simplify many queries and will allow to get rid of `FROM_UNIXTIME` calls everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
select a.month, a.year, (billable + non_billable) total, billable, non_billable
from (select month, year, sum(hours) billable
      from dpd_harvest_entries
      where task_id in (2, 3)
      group by month, year) a,
     (select month, year, sum(hours) non_billable
      from dpd_harvest_entries
      where task_id in (1))
      group by month, year) b
where a.month = b.month
and a.year = b.year
```

I am assuming you can convert the timestamps to month and year

Answer (score 0):

You would need 2 sub queries (billable and non-billable), have a column year-month in both of them and then join them on your year-month column to bring them together, something like this:

```
SELECT 
billable.year_month as year_month,
billable.sum_hours as billable_hours,
non_billable.sum_hours as non_billable_hours,
(billable.sum_hours + non_billable.sum_hours) as total_hours

FROM (SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at), '%Y-%m') as year_month,
SUM(hours) as sum_hours
FROM dpd_harvest_entries
WHERE task_id IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY
1) as billable,

(SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(logged_at), '%Y-%m') as year_month,
SUM(hours) as sum_hours
FROM dpd_harvest_entries
WHERE task_id IN (4,5,6)
GROUP BY
1) as non_billable

LEFT JOIN billable on billable.year_month = non_billable.year_month
```

Careful with the join type here; this will skip months if you have no billable or non billable hours in a month. Not sure what join type you would need in your case.